# Debugging PDO queries, how?

Tags: php, debugging, pdo

I'm having trouble with some of the more complicated queries sent through PDO using prepared statements. While errorInfo() is useful in showing syntax errors, it doesn't really show logic errors and what is actually part of the query.

Is there a way to echo out the query that PDO executed last? As in, the actual query sent to database? The class should store it somewhere right, because it does send it to database somewhere? Is there a method or some way of catching it?

Currently my debugging system echoes out only the query with ? in place of actual parameters, which is less useful if the error is in logic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [PDOStatement::debugDumpParams](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php)? It gives you detailed information about parameters.

From the manual:

> Dumps the informations contained by a prepared statement directly on the output. It will provide the SQL query in use, the number of parameters used (Params), the list of parameters, with their name, type (paramtype) as an integer, their key name or position, the value, and the position in the query (if this is supported by the PDO driver, otherwise, it will be -1).

Comment: So it is confusing. Going by the description it says it dumps "the value" of the parameter. But the examples on manual page doesn't seem to be outputting values. I do not have a php system at hand. Let me knows if this worked for you.

Comment: Not really an option, but it seems to be the only thing that PDO gives as output. No wonder it is tough to get people using PDO when debugging database operations have been made so difficult that the only way seems to be to manually extend the class and build a query builder within it for that exact purpose. I'm forced to accept this as the answer unless someone comes up with a better alternative.

Comment: This dump params also literally dumps, which is really strange. I'd expect it to return an array or something that can be easily stored without having to catch it with output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying mysql-proxy: http://lamp-dev.com/wp-content/uploads/mysql-proxy.zip

It doesn't matter what extension you use in php , it is just in the middle between php and mysql acting as proxy and shows you all queries "as is". You just need to change DSN in start.bat. Note that this version is windows based.

You'll need to change your connection in php then to connect it to mysql-proxy

Forgot to say that this makes sense only if you use mysql, you did not specify your RDBMS, PDO may work with different drivers

Comment: While I do use MySQL, the framework I am developing needs to be database-independent and I need such a support for all supported PDO databases, if possible. So this sadly doesn't help. But thank you!